# Unable to import a column from csv into NLTK using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science

I am unable to tokenize data from csvfile into nltk

this is my code

```
import nltk
import csv
import numpy

from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag

reader = csv.reader(open('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/dingdang/tweets.csv', 'rU'), delimiter= ",",quotechar='|')
tokenData = nltk.word_tokenize(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize

data=pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/dingdang/tweets.csv')

#Considering tweets to be present in 'text' column.
Texts=list(data['text'].values)

tokenData = [nltk.word_tokenize(tweet) for tweet in Texts]
```

tokenData is a list of word_tokenized lists.

Comment: Can you share some data instances from tweets.csv?